# Setting the value of a kendo telerik command column in a grid

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am trying to set the value (the text within the button) of a command column in a Telerik MVC grid.

I have this code:

```
columns.Command(o => o.Custom("ActivationCode").Text("\\#=ActivationCode\\#").Click("showDetails")).Width(180);
```

What I am trying to do is have the text inside the button render as the value of the underlying data model. Example value would be AY63P9 for example.

Using the Text() method it just renders the value in that function, it does not insert the bound value.

I have also tried using

```
columns.Command(o => o.Custom("ActivationCode").Click("showDetails")).Width(180).Title("\\#=ActivationCode\\#");
```

But I receive the same error message - "ActivationCode is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You can name the button using jQuery.

Declare `DataBound` event for the grid as below,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.TempTable>()
.Name("tempData")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Width(100);
    columns.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Custom("ActivationCode").Text("");
    }).Width(100);
})
.Events(e => { e.DataBound("tempData_DataBound"); })
```

In `DataBound` method, get the value you want to assign. For example, get the first column value (Name column) and assign it to the button.

```
function tempData_DataBound(e) {
    var tmpTable = $('#tempData').find('table tbody');
    var rowCnt = e.sender._data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCnt; i++) {
        var _tempName = $(tmpTable).find('tr:eq('+ i +') td:eq(0)').html();
        $(tmpTable).find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('.k-grid-ActivationCode').text(_tempName);
    }        
}
```

The result is

[image]